# What is the "~/" directory?

Tags: shell, directory, directory-structure

I'm trying to locate where some files are stored and I can easily browse to them via ssh by going to "cd ~/foldername", however, I have no idea what directory "~/" actually is.

When I browse around folders via WinSCP (yes, I'm a Windows admin), I can't seem to locate this folder at all.

**Note:** I'm using Amazon Linux on EC2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tilde character is shorthand for the home directory of the current logged-in user. If you are logged in as jason, then `~` is likely `/home/jason/`. It is the home directory of any username, *as given in /etc/passwd*. It is also the same as the $HOME environment variable. The expansion from `~` to the home directory is done by the shell.

Comment: That is what I thought, but I can't seem to locate the folder under my home directory. The full directory I'm looking for it "~/.ec2"...does adding that period make the folder invisible or something? I'm able to browse to it via ssh without issue, but it doesn't show up under WinSCP.

Comment: I figured out my issue...I had sudo'ed to the root user to make the file I was looking for, so the folder I was looking for was actually under /root rather than /home/user. 

This information was helpful in any case though, thanks!

Comment: Will award the answer once I'm able to in 8 minutes. Thanks for the quick response everybody.

Comment: It is expanded by the shell, try `echo ~`. There's not even a folder with that name, because any command getting it as an argument will actually be passed the value of `$HOME`, not `~`.

Comment: @JasonDavis Yup, this is not really a shorthand for `/home/$(whoami)` but for whatever your home directory is. In some systems, regular uses have those under `/usr/`, and I think `root`'s `$HOME` used to be `/`.

Comment: Fantastic and quick response...thanks everybody.

Comment: `~` actually expands to the current value of `$HOME`, not *necessarily* to the current user's home directory. Normally they'll be the same, but it is possible to modify the value of `$HOME`. (This is rarely a good idea.) On the other hand, `~foo` does expand to the home directory of user `foo` as defined in `/etc/passwd` or in your system's equivalent.

Comment: @njsg, `~/file` expands just to `$HOME/file`, and the environment variable `HOME` is set on login from your `/etc/passwd` entry (or wherever it comes from). You are free to change its value. Any resulting pain is then self-inflicted.